# com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory

Tags: android, google-api-java-client

Just download google api java client
**google-api-java-client-1.13.2-beta.zip**

and try [the sample there][1] 
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/

I have already copy the into "libs" folder

But

**import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory**

can not be resolved....

Any comment helps, THANKS...

Answer (score 2):

please follow this
, and it will solve your problems.

[image]

Comment: Add "which" to Build Path ? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but not work.  I have added all the 10 jar file to Build Path (the 10 jar files, https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup#Download_Library_with_Dependencies mentioned).

Answer (score 1):

After trying Google API Java Client Version 1.11.0 and it' OK  now.

Looks like Google change it on Version 1.13.x